# How to get multiple counts in one sql query across multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables

Company & products

I need to get 2 counts. One is the total count of products and the secondly count of products for sale_flg=1

This SQL does not seem to work..Tried several other ways..not able to get the expected results

```
SELECT A.COMPANY_NAME, COUNT(B.PRODUCT_ID) AS TOTAL_COUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, 
       (CASE WHEN B.SALEFLG =1 THEN 1 END) AS COUNT_OF_SALES
FROM COMPANY A LEFT JOIN
     PRODUCT B
     ON B.COMPANY_ID = A.COMPANY_ID
GROUP BY A.COMPANY_NAME
```

Comment: SELECT A.COMPANY_NAME,
COUNT(B.PRODUCT_ID) AS TOTAL_COUNT_OF_PRODUCTS,
(CASE WHEN B.SALEFLG =1 THEN 1 END) AS COUNT_OF_SALES 
FROM COMPANY A LEFT JOIN PRODUCT B ON B.COMPANY_ID=A.COMPANY_ID
GROUP BY A.COMPANY_NAME

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need a sum for the `case`:

```
SELECT C.COMPANY_NAME, COUNT(P.PRODUCT_ID) AS TOTAL_COUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN P.SALEFLG = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT_OF_SALES
FROM COMPANY C LEFT JOIN
     PRODUCT P
     ON P.COMPANY_ID = C.COMPANY_ID
GROUP BY C.COMPANY_NAME ;
```

Comment: The sql works with no errors but the sum is not giving me the right result as we only have a handful of records that have sale flag =1

Comment: Is there any other option

Comment: @SQLUser . . . You need to provide sample data and desired results, as I already requested in a comment.

Comment: Company name  Total_Product_Count   Total_Products_for_Sale (where Sale_flg=1)
XYZ         25                    10
ABC             10                    5

Comment: @SQLUser - count(CASE WHEN B.SALEFLG =1 THEN 1 else null END) AS COUNT_OF_SALES use this

Comment: Not sure this matters, but in some places you are saying `saleflg` and in others `sale_flg` if you have both, make sure the query references the right one. You have provided sample output in comments, but we'd like sample data from the source tables.

Comment: There are many possibilities which are hard to second guess without seeing table structure (including primary keys). One possibility: there could be another field which indicates that a product is discontinued and the query isn't handling that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have B.SALEFLG = 1 or 0 for you may try

```
Sum(B.SALEFLG) AS COUNT_OF_SALES
```

Or use UNION

Answer (score 0):

If you use count then in else you should consider null because null is not consider in count aggregation and if you have B.SALEFLG =1 or 0 then use sum aggregation.

You can try below code:

```
SELECT A.COMPANY_NAME, COUNT(B.PRODUCT_ID) AS TOTAL_COUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, 
       count(CASE WHEN B.SALEFLG =1 THEN 1 else null END) AS COUNT_OF_SALES
FROM COMPANY A LEFT JOIN
     PRODUCT B
     ON B.COMPANY_ID = A.COMPANY_ID
GROUP BY A.COMPANY_NAME
```

OR try this:

```
SELECT A.COMPANY_NAME, COUNT(B.PRODUCT_ID) AS TOTAL_COUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, 
       sum(B.SALEFLG) AS COUNT_OF_SALES
FROM COMPANY A LEFT JOIN
     PRODUCT B
     ON B.COMPANY_ID = A.COMPANY_ID
GROUP BY A.COMPANY_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

This SQL server query is working.
Company Table and Product Table
Company Table CompanyID is join with Product table and sales_flg add in product table .

### sales_flg = 1 record display in CntSalesflg

```
select Comp.CompID as CompID, COUNT(Pro.ProductID) as CntProdustID, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Pro.SalesflagID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CntSalesflg
from Product as Pro
inner join Company as Comp on Pro.CompID = Comp.CompID
GROUP by Comp.CompID
```